# Keep a list of work to do in the future

Tags: c++, c++11

Since function pointers need to know what arguments are supplied ahead of time I don't know how to do this.

Essentially I want a list of work. Each entry is a function to be called with specific arguments. I.e. I want to add `foo(3, "abcd")` to the work list, and then later `bar(&h)`. That is, I don't know beforehand what types of functions will be added.

Later I will the iterate over this list and do the function calls specified.

Can this be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::function<void()>` represents something that can be invoked, and returns nothing.

The clearest thing to store in it is a lambda.

```
std::function<void()> f = []{ foo(3, "abcd"); };
```

stores "call `foo( 3, "abcd" );` in the `std::function` called `f`.

We can build a list of them -- a `std::deque` or `std::vector` -- and call them at a later time.

You can capture state in a lambda by putting what you want to capture within the `[]`s:

```
std::function<void()> g = [h]{ bar(&h); };
```

This copies `h` into the lambda, then calls `bar` with a pointer to `h`.  Sometimes you'll want `h` to be mutable:

```
std::function<void()> g = [h]()mutable{ bar(&h); };
```

You can also have lambdas that store references to variables.  This is dangerous, as you are responsible for lifetime, and if you are storing the lambdas within `std::function`s then storing those in a container, lifetime may not be simple.

In C++14 you can even put expressions in the `[]`s.

`std::function<void()>` behaves like a value.  You invoke it with `()`, just like calling a function with signature `void()`.

Using `std::bind` instead of lambdas is technically possible, but `std::bind` has many strange quirks and the code generated is usually less clear and errors are almost always unreadable.  Don't do it.

You can also do this with a custom function object.

```
struct custom {
  std::string s;
  void operator()() const {
    foo( 3, s );
  }
};
```

Then `std::function<void()> f = custom{ "abcd" };` is another way to say you'll invoke `foo` with `3, std::string("abcd")` later when you `f()` on `f`.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and either lambdas, or [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

`std::function` is a wrapper for an arbitrary callable. You can store anything in it on which you can call `operator()` with the appropriate arguments.

One thing you can store in it are lambdas: you'd encapsulate the call and arguments into a non-argument lambda and call that.

Another thing you can store is the result of `std::bind`. `std::bind` is effectively a metafunction: it takes a function *f* and arguments as input, and returns a function object whose invocation results in invoking *f* on the arguments.

Here's how you could apply this to your case. The common setup:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> workList;

fillWorkList(workList);

for (auto& f : workList)
  f();
```

And here are two possible implementations of `fillWorkList`. One with `std::bind`:

```
void fillWorkList(std::vector<std::function<void()>>& workList)
{
  workList.push_back(std::bind(foo, 3, "abcd"));
  workList.push_back(std::bind(bar, &h));
}
```

And one with lambdas:

```
void fillWorkList(std::vector<std::function<void()>>& workList)
{
  workList.push_back([]() { foo(3, "abcd"); });
  workList.push_back([]() { bar(&h); });
}
```

Comment: How would you specify foo(3, "abcd") or bar(&h) as an argument to a function? I. e. arbitrary functions with arbitrary arguments.

Comment: @JensJensen The compiler would assume that you are passing the return value. I.e. it would evaluate the expression. You need to use bind or wrap it in a lambda in order to pass a callable object as a parameter.

Comment: @JensJensen That's what this answer shows. Compose it from `std::bind`, or wrap it in a lambda. Can you clarify what you don't understand?

Comment: Wouldn't `h` have to be captured by the lambda?

Comment: So, could you call a function add_work(foo, 3, 'abcd') and have the argument be specified as std::bind binding?

Comment: Woops, of course I meant add_work(std::bind(foo, 3, 'abcd')). I guess you could. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you telling someone to use `std::bind` at all, let alone as your first examples?

Comment: @Yakk Call me weird, but for me in this particular case (delaying a function's invocation), `std::bind ` is more intuitive and more comprehensible than using a lambda. It's precisely what it's for, after all: bind a function's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, [using a parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), and [perfect forwarding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) that allows for `add(foo, 3, "abcd")` to be used:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

void foo(int val, std::string text) { std::cout << val << '\t' << text << '\n'; }
void bar(int* ptr) { std::cout << *ptr << '\n'; }

class Worklist {
public:
    template <typename ...Args>
    void add(Args&&... args) {
        worklist.push_back(std::bind(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

    void do_all()
    {
        for(auto& i : worklist) {
            i();
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> worklist;
};

int main()
{
    int h{9};
    Worklist worklist;
    worklist.add(foo, 3, "abcd");
    worklist.add(bar,&h);
    worklist.do_all();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write a class that will accept lambdas as the tasks without using `std::bind` or `std::function`.

Here, a `std::unique_ptr` is used to store each of the lambdas:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

void foo(int val, std::string text) { std::cout << val << '\t' << text << '\n'; }
void bar(int* ptr) { std::cout << *ptr << '\n'; }

class Generic_Callable {
public:
    ~Generic_Callable() = default;
    virtual void call() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class MyCallable : public Generic_Callable {
public:
    MyCallable(T &&t) : ptr{std::make_unique<T>(std::move(t))} {}

    void call() override
    {
        (*ptr)();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<T> ptr;
};

class Worklist {
public:
    template <typename T>
    void add(T &&t)
    {
        worklist.push_back(std::make_unique<MyCallable<T>>(std::move(t)));
    }

    void do_all() {
        for(auto& i : worklist)
            i->call();
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Generic_Callable>> worklist;
};


int main()
{
    int h{9};
    Worklist worklist;
    worklist.add([]() {foo(3, "abcd"); });
    worklist.add([&h]() {bar(&h); });
    worklist.do_all();
}
```